# Can I put the article 'the' before a proper noun which also has common noun after it?

Tags: usage, definite-article

Can a proper noun (*Oxford University*) take *the* if it is followed by a common noun (*journal*), like in the following sentence?

> We can get more data in *the* Oxford University journal.

Comment: "the Oxford University journal" looks like a "proper noun" to me, since the implication of the *definite* article is that there is only *one* such publication (perhaps with many different ***issues*** if it's a monthly or annual publication).  If it *wasn't* a "proper noun", that would require the ***indefinite*** article - ***an** Oxford University journal*.

Comment: There are more than 500 journals published by Oxford University, so there is not a singular "the journal" which is "the Oxford University journal." None of them contain the words "Oxford University" together, either. So, as written, the sentence thus seems incorrect.  "We can get more data in **one of the** Oxford University journals. Which one? here's a list: https://academic.oup.com/journals/pages/journals_a_to_z

Comment: @FumbleFingers you are correct but can you tell me answer if there can be 'the' before a proper noun a common noun follows it. I can't think of any example as of  now.

Comment: There are lots of situations where "the" or "a" comes before a proper noun *which is being used as a "noun adjunct" to modify an "ordinary" noun that follows*. For example, *I commute to work on **the London train***, or *He met **an Oxford University student***.